# Theta Notation for N to the Power of Log Manipulation

Tags: time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity, big-o

In Asymptotic Notations for Order of Growth; Is the form

```
Theta(N ^ ( ( LOGb( a / b) + 1 ) ) )
```

Equivalent to

```
Theta(N ^ (LOGb( a ) ) ) ??
```

Where LOGb(a) means LOG a to base b.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since log(a/b) = log a - log b and LOGb(b) = 1, we have LOGb(a/b)-1 = LOGb(a) - 1 + 1 = LOGb(a). No mention of asymptotics necessary, this equality is exact for all a, b > 0.

Comment: Thank you! My mathematics is too rusty. Any suggestions?!